# Количекство строк в SQL

Tags: count, sql-server, sql

Дублирует общее кол-во строк, а должно показывать по отдельному значению. К примеру в 1й строке 1го столбца "Высшее" а во втором столбце кол-во записей из второй таблицы, где происходит совпадение

```
    select sp2.NAIM, 
        (select COUNT(*) 
        from KDK 
        inner join kdk1 on kdk.N_KDK=kdk1.N_KDK
        inner join SP2 on sp2.KOD_N=KDK1.KK02
        where kdk1.KK02=sp2.KOD_N and sp2.SPR='k02' and KDK.KPOL=1) as Male

from SP2  where sp2.SPR='k02'
```

Comment: Вы, скорее всего, "дубли" строк получили JOIN'ами. Хотя без структуры таблиц сожно точно сказать

Comment: может кто привести более удобный пример, аналогичный этому
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175997.aspx 
(самый последний)

Comment: @Владислав Сергеевич, создайте пример вашей структуры на http://sqlfiddle.com
разобраться в ваших названиях колонок и таблиц не представляется возможным.

Comment: не открывается на работе сайт
вот файлик с полями табл
http://rghost.ru/private/52332455/38557ba6ac6cd55c06102d9764233050

Answer (score 1):

По вашей структуре:

1. необходимости в kdk1 вообще нет, там содержатся те же данные что и в kdk
2. для подсчета количества вложенный запрос не нужен

Итого:

```
select sp2.naim, COUNT(*) as Male
from kdk 
  inner join sp2 on sp2.kod_n=kdk.kk02
where 
  sp2.spr = 'k02'
  and kdk.kpol = 1
group by sp2.naim
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77658/3)

ЗЫ **upd**. с декартовым произведением поторопился, да

Comment: а как насчёт того, что бы вывелась 3я колонка с условием kdk.kpol = 2

Comment: + в колонке с условием kdk.kpol = 2 10 строк а с kdk.kpol = 1 12 строк. Я так понимаю, нужно копать  в направлении сводных таблиц\матриц

Comment: @Владислав Сергеевич, это будет другой запрос, разумеется. вы не сказали какой у вас sql server, в 2012 можно так: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/77658/1  
в 2008 аналогично через case...